# Change appearance of URLs with htaccess mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

It's really tough to find clear explanations of the Rewrite Engine syntax anywhere. Regular expressions are familiar, but the rest of it is alien to me.

Is there no way to hide `http://` or `https://` in the URL that is displayed in the address bar?

My directory looks like this.

```
public_html/
    example/
        index.php
        whatever.php
```

## Issue #1

This is currently what's happening, which obviously all over the place.

```
URL THAT IS TYPED IN                         URL THAT DISPLAYS

https://www.example.com -------------------> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -----------------------> https://example.com
http://www.example.com --------------------> https://www.example.com/example/index.php
http://example.com ------------------------> https://example.com/example/index.php
www.example.com ---------------------------> https://www.example.com/example/index.php
example.com -------------------------------> https://example.com/example/index.php
```

The first thing I'd like to do is always force the following.

```
URL THAT IS TYPED IN                          URL THAT DISPLAYS

https://www.example.com/example/index.php --> example.com/index
https://www.example.com --------------------> example.com
https://example.com ------------------------> example.com
http://www.example.com ---------------------> example.com
http://example.com -------------------------> example.com
www.example.com ----------------------------> example.com
example.com --------------------------------> example.com
```

## Issue #2

The second thing I'd like to do, which I just figured out how to do, is clean up the URLs for sub-directories and files.

```
ACCESS TO THIS FILE PATH                      URL THAT DISPLAYS

example.com/example/index.php --------------> example.com/index
```

I know this can be done with the following `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteRule ^index /mydomain/index.php [NC]
```

But I'd also like to force the URLs to display in the following way no matter what.

```
URL THAT IS TYPED IN                          URL THAT DISPLAYS

https://www.example.com/example/index.php --> example.com/index
https://example.com/example/index.php ------> example.com/index
http://www.example.com/example/index.php ---> example.com/index
http:/example.com/example/index.php --------> example.com/index
www.example.com/example/index.php ----------> example.com/index
mydomain.com/example/index.php -------------> example.com/index

https://www.example.com/index.php ----------> example.com/index
https://example.com/index.php --------------> example.com/index
http://www.example.com/index.php -----------> example.com/index
http:/example.com/index.php ----------------> example.com/index
www.example.com/index.php ------------------> example.com/index
mydomain.com/index.php ---------------------> example.com/index

https://www.example.com/index --------------> example.com/index
https://example.com/index ------------------> example.com/index
http://www.example.com/index ---------------> example.com/index
http://example.com/index -------------------> example.com/index
www.example.com/index ----------------------> example.com/index
example.com/index --------------------------> example.com/index
```

I did just find [this,](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever) so I'm going to start reading right after dinner.

I also came across [this](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet/) right now, but I'm still struggling to wrap my head around this.

## My Progress So Far

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login$
RewriteRule ^login /index.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dashboard$
RewriteRule ^dashboard /dashboard.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/logout$
RewriteRule ^logout /includes/destroy.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.birddogdata\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://birddogdata.com [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The only issue I have yet to figure out is how to get `example.com` to redirect to `example.com/login`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Is there no way to hide http:// or https:// in the URL that is displayed in the address bar?"* - not really (though some browsers hide it themselves), that's the protocol that determines *how* you're connecting to that address. `http` connects on port 80 (by default) and transmits data in plain text, `https` on the other hand connects on port 443 (by default) and performs a TLS handshake first so that any data transferred between the client and server is encrypted.

Comment: The `http` and `https` domains are also configured separately in the Apache config (httpd-vhosts.conf) - they can have completely different document routes if you want. The same is true for sub-domains, so `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` *could* all resolve to completely different places - so your desired *"display"* routing doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Essentially, I think you've got the idea of `mod_rewrite` slightly backwards - it's not for manipulating what's displayed in the address bar on the client but for taking what's entered in the address bar and sending it somewhere else. If you want to have someone type `example.com/index` and load the resource from `http://www.example.com/index.php` then a mix of DNS and Apache configuration combined with mod_rewrite is the way to go ... the other way around, JavaScript is probably your best bet.

Comment: @CD001 but it essentially does both things right. when i use `RewriteRule ^index /mydomain/index.php [NC]` and when somebody searches for `example.com/index`, it serves `example.com/example/index.php`  and `example.com/index` is displayed

Comment: Yes... but if anyone entered `example.com/example/index.php` then that wouldn't be rewritten (as that's the real resource) and that's what would be displayed in the address bar.

Comment: But that is where redirects come in, no? on my own site, even if you go directly to `example.com/index.php` it redirects to `https://example.com`. if u go to `example.com/dashboard.php` it redirects to `example.com/login` aka `index.php`

Comment: Yes - you can do that as well (though example.com/index.php -> example.com could just be directory indexing), you just have to watch for infinite loops (e.g. inadvertently rewriting a file to itself). Normally when using a PHP routing script you only redirect URLs which point to resources that **don't** actually exist by using a couple of rewrite conditions with the `!-f` (not a file) and `!-d` (not a directory) flags - which is what I was referring to.

Comment: i can show you what i've done so far. i'll update my question